# Get the title and/or link of the parent website in javascript in SP2013

Tags: 2013, javascript, site, spcontext

Is it possible somehow in JavaScript to acquire the title and/or link of the parent of my current site?

I know that I can create a client context with a specific URL, but is it possible to do this relatively, so that the script can run on any website and catch the parent?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the REST API to get the Title.

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/parentWeb
```

Dev Center:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246539(v=office.15).aspx